# If $\{x_n\}$ converges to zero and we have $|x_{n+1}/x_n|$ is bounded then $|x_{n+1}/x_n|$ has a limit.

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

This is a situation that appears frequently in numerical analysis say $\{x_n\}$ converges to zero and we have $|x_{n+1}/x_n|$ is bounded. Then I need to prove (not convinced it is true though) that $|x_{n+1}/x_n|$ has a finite limit.

Could you give me a proof outline or a counterexample?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be a counterexample: define recursively $$\begin{cases}x_0=1\\ x_{n+1}=\frac13 x_n&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\x_{n+1}=\frac12 x_n&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

A.k.a. $$1,\,\frac13,\,\frac16\,,\frac1{18}\,,\frac{1}{36},\cdots$$